# A user registration class

Tags: php, class, registration

I'm writing this in PHP, but, generally speaking, what methods and properties would a user (registration?) class have? I know I can use MDB2 from PEAR for database abstraction, and one feature I can think of is making sure the username is valid.

```
$user->validateUserName($username, $regex);
```

Can anybody think of any more?

Thanks.

**Edit**:

Username validation would be a class of its own right (Validator class or something)?

Comment: I think, that yes. You should have a separate class with validation methods. Also you should distinctly describe, what is your question and not confuse support people with `(registration?)`. Stick to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a such class at all. Registration is a whole process of receiving data, validating that data and finally, processing validated data if validation succeed. In other words: registration is that part of code which uses some object to solve a given problem.

What will you need?

1. An object that represents a single user.
2. An object that takes `User` object and saves it.
3. Some validation mechanism (it will use at least several objects).

Let's design an interface. How will we use the code we're going to write?

```
try {
    $validator = new Validator($_POST);
    $validator->addRules(array(
        'username' => new LengthValidator(array('min' => 3, 'max' => 15)),
        'password' => array(
            new LengthValidator(array('min' => 6))
            new RegexpValidator(array('pattern' => '#...#'))
        ),
        'email'    => array(
            new EmailValidator(),
            new UniqueValidator(....)
         )
    ));

    $data = $validator->validate();

    $userService = new UserService($databaseHandler, $someOtherArguments);

    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($data['username']);
    $user->setPassword($data['password']);
    $user->setEmail($data['email']);
    $user->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
    $user->setLastname($data['lastname']);

    $userService->save($user);
} catch (ValidationException $ve) {
   // validation failed
}
```

That's of course only an example - it can be designed totally different way.

Comment: It should be designed differently. If you use such logic, then you should have some main class and other as drivers. Like in Zend. Also such classes look better if they have static methods.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I has been inventing (not sure whether that's a right word in this context ;]) that code during writing the answer. *should have some main class and other as drivers*  That applies to what? Validation/User? Of curse it could be - that's just an example. *Also such classes look better if they have static methods.* Where exactly a static method should be used in this code?

Comment: I won't agree about the errors handler : exceptions are for exceptional errors. An invalid e-mail format is an expected error (most of the time, depends of software goals).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should check if

- Username is already in use
- Password is strong enough
- User's Mail address is valid

You also need methods to

- create a new account
- change User's data
- delete an existing account?
- allow Users to recover forgotten pws

Comment: Downvote: basics of OOP: [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: All last for suggestions are incorrect. You forget, that this is not user manager class. It's only for registration. You might wanna look into ZF.

Comment: This class has only on responsibility: Manage User data (including add, edit and delete a user)

Comment: In title of the question I see clearly "A user registration class". It should mean, that this class should validate data form registration form and if everything is okey, then add user.

Comment: @Eugene IMHO OP is not sure about if he only want's a registration class or a user class. See in the question "user (registration?) class"

Comment: Question must be distincly described. This is not a quest where there can be many possibilities. You either know what you need or you don't.

Answer (score 0):

ValidForm, it's a great class structured to handle your forms both client/server-sided. However, no MySQL is passed through the form.